# How to create a div with set size in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I got some starter code from a tutorial and I've been struggling to set the correct size. I've tried to find solutions via documentation but I feel like I'm missing something very basic. The issue that I am having is that the size of the box changes based on the content that is inside. I'd like a definitive size set regardless of the inside content. This is my code for the section:

```
<div className="flex flex-wrap -m-4">
      {projects.map((project) => (
        <a 
          href={project.link}
          key={project.image}
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
          className="flex w-1/2 h-full p-4">
          <div className="flex relative">
            <img
              alt="gallery"
              className="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full rounded-2xl object-cover object-center border-4 border-white"
              src={project.image}
            />
            <div className="px-8 py-10 relative z-0 w-full rounded-2xl border-4 border-gray-800 bg-gray-900 opacity-0 hover:opacity-100">
              <h2 className="tracking-widest text-sm title-font font-medium text-orange-700 mb-1">
                {project.subtitle}
              </h2>
              <h1 className="title-font text-lg font-medium text-white mb-3">
                {project.title}
              </h1>
              <p className="leading-relaxed">{project.description}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your a tag you have `className="flex w-1/2 h-full p-4">` updating the `h-full` to be the specified height that you want should do the trick. The tailwind numbers will provide a value in `em` I believe. To get these to be a `px` value you can write the style like this: `h-[50px]` but include your desired height in the square brackets instead of teh `50px`.

Comment: Tailwind numbers are in  0.25 `rem`, which is usually 16px. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing#default-spacing-scale